# Run Bash Commands in Parallel and Exit Both of Them

Tags: bash

I have the following script that I want to run. The problem is that it doesn't gracefully exit; when I press `Ctrl-C` only compass terminates, but `runserver` is still going in the background and needs to be manually killed. Is there a way to get both of these to exit gracefully? If not through `Ctrl-C`, is there something else I should be using to kill these processes together?

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/venv
source ./bin/activate
service gunicorn stop
cd /path/www/static/sass_sorting
compass watch &
/path/venv/djo/manage.py runserver &
```

Comment: Are you saying that even though this script puts both `compass` and `path/venv/djo/manage.py  runserver` into the background, you can kill `compass` with a `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: yes, that is what is happening

Comment: Unless `compass` is checking the keyboard for ctrl-C, I'm not sure how that's happening unless you press ctrl-C before the process has a chance to really get started. If you run a command in the background with the shell using `&` and the process actually gets started (you see the pid displayed), then ctrl-C shouldn't be sending a kill signal to the process. I know this isn't answering your question directly, but this condition is puzzling.

Comment: `compass` is not killed by Ctrl-C -- it exits gracefully. Even though it is executed in the background (with the `&` operator) it still belongs to the same process group of the script and the shell, so it receives SIGINT normally as if it was in the foreground, and it terminates normally.

Answer (score 1):

The `-p` option to `jobs` will return a list of background jobs that are still running. You can pass that to `kill` in a signal handler.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' SIGINT
cd /path/venv
source ./bin/activate
service gunicorn stop
cd /path/www/static/sass_sorting
compass watch &
/path/venv/djo/manage.py runserver &
```

If there might be jobs that you want to leave running, then save the process IDs of the background jobs you might want to kill.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill $p1 $p2' SIGINT
cd /path/venv
source ./bin/activate
service gunicorn stop
cd /path/www/static/sass_sorting
compass watch & p1=$!
/path/venv/djo/manage.py runserver & p2=$!
```

There is an unavoidable race condition, in that a process may always complete between the time you check if it is still running and when you actually try to kill it, so you can simply ignore any errors from `kill` about "no such process".

Comment: This isn't ending runserver. I get Error: That port is already in use. after Ctrl-Cing out of the script and rerunning it.

Answer (score 0):

Catch SIGINT with a command that would kill the processes, and use a loop that checks if processes still exist.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /ssdhome/development/matthew-server/venv
source ./bin/activate
service gunicorn stop
cd /ssdhome/development/matthew-server/www/static/sass_sorting

compass watch &
p1=$!
/ssdhome/development/matthew-server/venv/djo/manage.py runserver &
p2=$!

trap 'kill "$p1"; kill "$p2"' SIGINT
while kill -s 0 "$p1" || kill -s 0 "$p2"; do
    wait "$p1"; wait "$p2"
done &>/dev/null
```

And instead of the default signal SIGTERM, you could also try SIGHUP or SIGABRT if it doesn't end your applications well:

```
trap 'kill -s SIGHUP "$p1"; kill -s SIGHUP "$p2"' SIGINT
```

Comment: This isn't ending `runserver`. I get `Error: That port is already in use.` after `Ctrl-C`ing out of the script and rerunning it.

Comment: @mh00h Probably the server that runs is not the process that you execute e.g. manage.py summons another process so naturally p2 would represent manage.py but not the actual process. Are there commands you use to stop the process? like manage.py stopserver, etc?

Comment: no- `manage.py` is for a django project and outputs a log to the terminal as connections come in. It stops when you `Ctrl-C` the terminal, but not in this script.